# 404 with ajax call in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to figure out why my MVC4 web application is able to make this ajax call

```
    $.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        serverData = result;
    }
});
```

on IIS7

but on IIS6 I get a 404 - http://x.x.x.x/MyController/GetData not found.
The difference I see is on IIS6 it is configured as an application.

I've tried variations on how I specify url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',

```
"MyController", "GetData"
"", "GetData"
```

with no luck yet

These are the routes I have in global.asax

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MyController", // Route name
            "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you view the source of the page with the AJAX function on it, what is MVC inserting for the URL? Is it correct?

Comment: A CF server app in prod was hijacking the request - in prod they use IISRewrite and require an empty .htaccess file at the root in  app directories otherwise all requests go via a default CF page.